# One time Sign-in

Tags: java, android, authentication

I am creating a project where I have a login screen, which is used for user to login into the
Application. This login screen should only be visible the first time, so the user can fill it and log in, but when user opens the application at the second time the application must show main.activity. How to use Shared preferences to do this?

Comment: use this link , demo also there , http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-session-management-using-shared-preferences/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the login information of the user in SharedPeference:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("preference",MODE_PRIVATE);
preferences.edit().putBoolean("LoggedIn", true).apply();
```

And save the boolean "LoggedIn" to false when the User logs out :

```
preferences.edit().putBoolean("LoggedIn", false).apply();
```

In the SplashActivity get the value from sharedprefence and call respective activities:

```
boolean loggedIn =  preferences.getBoolean("LoggedIn", false);

if(loggedIn){
// call main activity
}else{
//call login activity
}
```

Comment: how it work? @madhuri HR

Comment: This saves the user login status even when the application is closed and opened. Hence you can call the respective activity when the application opens. @Rushabh042

Answer (score 1):

First, check whether user logged in before. Use SharedPreferences:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
Boolean loggedIn = prefs.getBoolean("loggedIn", false);
if(loggedIn != null && loggedIn)
{
    //open main activity
}else{
    //open login page
}
```

and when user logs in, save the login information to SharedPreferences:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
prefs.edit().putBoolean("loggedIn", true);
```

That is all you need.

Comment: what is (getActivity()) its shows error

Comment: @Rushabh042 in which class are you trying to write this code? Are you in an activity or in a fragment?

Comment: @Rushabh042 if you are in an activity, you can just use PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());

Comment: i write upper code in my splash screen and the lower code is in my method @bigO

Comment: are you there ? @bigO

Comment: @Rushabh042 do you get an error? Can you explain more what did not work?

Comment: i did't get error but it's can't work @bigO

Answer (score 0):

SIf you want to do this with shared preferences when the user log in to the app share a preference..

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("MyApp", MODE_PRIVATE);
prefs.edit().putBoolean("staylogin", true).commit();
```

And if you want to log out on buton click set the preference..

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("MyApp", MODE_PRIVATE);
prefs.edit().putBoolean("staylogin", false).commit();
```

In order to start your app without log in screen you can use a splash screen before the others and check the shared preference...

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("MyApp", MODE_PRIVATE);
Boolean state = prefs.getString("staylogin", false);

if (state) {

//Start Main Activity

} else {

//Start Log in activity

}
```

Comment: it showing error at (state==0) Why? @Nikos Mitropoulos

Comment: Yes i have made mistake because  i use prefs.getString("staylogin", "UNKNOWN") and put it in int value...i edit my answer..thanks for your comment.

Comment: Why i always got state 1 in Your code ? @Nikos Mitropoulos

Comment: Are you sure that you used properly the code prefs.edit().putString("staylogin", "0").commit() when the user press the log out button? @Rushabh042

Comment: yes i am sure. @Nikos Mitropoulos

Comment: i got it.In your answer Use boolean instead of string.@Nikos Mitropoulos

Comment: Its the same..the only difference is the way that you check your value in if..

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Working code

in your Login page

```
    // Session Manager Class
        SessionManagerFor_Signin session;

    private EditText EMAIL, PASSWORD;
        private Button login;

    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

            setContentView(R.layout.sign_in);

            // Session Manager
            session = new SessionManagerFor_Signin(getApplicationContext());

    login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginbutton);

            EMAIL = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EmaileditText1);
            PASSWORD = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordeditText2);

    login.setOnClickListener(this);


    }
    @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.loginbutton:

    email = EMAIL.getText().toString();
    password = PASSWORD.getText().toString();

if (email.equals("") || password.equals(""))
            {
                // user didn't entered user name or password
                // Show alert asking him to enter the details
                alert.showAlertDialog(sign_in.this, "Login Failed...","Please Enter Email and Password", false);

            } 

            else
            {

                // fetch the Password form database for respective Email
                storedPassword = DB.getSinlgeEntry(email);

                if (password.equals(storedPassword)) 
                {

    session.createLoginSession(email, password);
    Toast.makeText(sign_in.this, "Login Successfull",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(sign_in.this, Page1_Landing.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
}
}
    break;
    }
```

SessionManagerFor_Signin.java

```
public class SessionManagerFor_Signin 
{
    // Shared Preferences
    SharedPreferences pref;

    // Editor for Shared preferences
    Editor editor;

    // Context
    Context _context;

    // Shared pref mode
    int PRIVATE_MODE = 0;

    // Sharedpref file name
    private static final String PREF_NAME = "SharedPref";

    // All Shared Preferences Keys
    private static final String IS_LOGIN = "IsLoggedIn";

    // User name (make variable public to access from outside)
    public static final String KEY_EMAILID = "email";

    // Email address (make variable public to access from outside)
    public static final String KEY_PASSWORD = "password";

    // Constructor
    public SessionManagerFor_Signin(Context context)
    {
        this._context = context;
        pref = _context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
        editor = pref.edit();

    }


     // Create login session

    public void createLoginSession(String email, String password)
    {
        // Storing login value as TRUE
        editor.putBoolean(IS_LOGIN, true);

        // Storing name in pref
        editor.putString(KEY_EMAILID, email);

        // Storing email in pref
        editor.putString(KEY_PASSWORD, password);

        // commit changes
        editor.commit();
    }   

    /**
     * Check login method wil check user login status
     * If false it will redirect user to login page
     * Else won't do anything
     * */
    public void checkLogin()
    {
        // Check login status

        if(this.isLoggedIn())
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(_context,Page1_Landing.class);
            // Closing all the Activities
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

            // Add new Flag to start new Activity
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),email, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            _context.startActivity(intent);
        }
        else
        {
            // user is not logged in redirect him to Login Activity
            Intent i = new Intent(_context, MainActivity.class);
            // Closing all the Activities
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

            // Add new Flag to start new Activity
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

            // Staring Login Activity
            _context.startActivity(i);
        }

    }



    /**
     * Get stored session data
     * */
    public HashMap<String, String> getUserDetails(){
        HashMap<String, String> user = new HashMap<String, String>();
        // user mail
        user.put(KEY_EMAILID, pref.getString(KEY_EMAILID, null));

        // user password
        user.put(KEY_PASSWORD, pref.getString(KEY_PASSWORD, null));

        // return user
        return user;
    }

    /**
     * Clear session details
     * */
    public void logoutUser()
    {
        // Clearing all data from Shared Preferences
        editor.clear();
        editor.commit();



        Intent intent = new Intent(_context,  MainActivity.class);

        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

        _context.startActivity(intent);
    }

    /**
     * Quick check for login
     * **/
    // Get Login State
    public boolean isLoggedIn()
    {
        return pref.getBoolean(IS_LOGIN, false);
    }
}
```

Further you want Reference Find below link

[Link For Reference](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-session-management-using-shared-preferences/)

Comment: what is the wrong in this code ? down voted

Comment: How to use checkLogin(), logoutUser(),isLoggedIn() @Mano

Comment: its did't work when application close and than open.it open re signning page @mano

Comment: you have to add this line in your  login button after successfill ,session.createLoginSession(email, password); then only it will save the status

Comment: iam using this code only in my app, logout option you only have to keep in some where in your app

Comment: in your edited answer What is storedPassword it showing error @mano

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79832/discussion-between-rushabh042-and-mano).