# How do remember that user signed up and take straight to another Activity?

Tags: android

The scenario is if the user downloads the app for first time, I ask them basic questions (say Activity A) and request them to sign up (Activity B).

This is a one time process only after installing the app. After that whenever they open the app, I am planning to take them straight away in to the app (Activity C).

How should I do this? I am a newbie to Android programming. But I am not able to think about this scenario. I don't want to use database.

Comment: Make use of preferences in your activity. if the preferences is set try to redirect to some other activity

Comment: use sharedpreference to store the user activity..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30664868/one-time-sign-in/30665342#30665342)

Comment: Please don't use StackOverflow as a means to take opinions. You can use http://chat.stackoverflow.com/ for this purpose. Moreover, since you're beginning to learn Android, you must check out http://developer.android.com as a reference. Also Googling can save your time and efforts many times. I just Googled "android remember user action" and found a relevant topic: [Saving Data](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/index.html). You can find answers quicker this way.

Answer (score 1):

You need a persistent storage mechanism to save the state of the user (logged in or not). There are various ways you can do this. The easiest is `SharedPreference` which will store the user state locally. You can also store this information in your remote server and validate user each time she opens the app although this might be going a bit overboard in most cases.

Comment: Assuming I don't want to save it in remote database, does shared preference state get lost after restarting or rebooting the android phone?

Comment: Since, local storage include `SharedPreference` belong to owner of the phone you cannot really rely on it much. Like a user may choose to `Clear Data` of your app and all your `SharedPreference` will get lost (the user would get logged off too) and you will have to regenerate it.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `SharedPreferences`. In `ActivityA` in on create check if SharedPreferences contain a certain value which decides if the user is signed up. If it not set or it does not have the required value, redirect the user to `ActivityB` or else `ActivityC`

**Code:**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    SharedPreferences pref  = this.getSharedPreferences("my_prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    if(pref.contains("MY_KEY") && pref.getBoolean("MY_KEY", false)){ //first stratup or user has not signed in yet
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityC.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    } else { //already signed up
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class); 
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

Dont forget to save/insert value inside `SharedPreferences` after the user sign up.

**Code:**

```
SharedPreferences pref  = this.getSharedPreferences("my_prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();

    if(sign_up_success){
        editor.putBoolean("MY_KEY", true);
        editor.commit();
    }
```

Comment: "Dont forget to save/insert value inside SharedPreferences after the user sign up."

You mean save it in database?

Comment: No in shared preferences

Answer (score 0):

The basic flow should be as follows `Splash Screen -> OnBoarding Screen(Signup) -> MainActivity` On the `Splash Screen` you need to check for a prefs value lets call it `isSignedUp` which is false if the user has not signed up. Its pretty straightforward from here. Every time you launch your app you need to check if the preference if `isSignedUp` is true or false and based on the value show the screen accordingly. So if the value is true that means the user has signed up and show him the main screen else show him the sing up screen.

Answer (score 0):

Use Android SharedPreferences, it can be used to store data which can be used to keep the answers in cache.